# Can I use DDR3-1066 ram in a laptop that takes DDR3-1333?

Tags: memory

A coworker has 2x 4gb of DDR3-1066 ram in an unused macbook, I have 2x 2gb of DDR3-1333 in a much newer laptop. I've heard that the number after is the maximum Mhz and that the computer handle, without overclocking. Should I swap the ram? Is it a bad idea?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is absolutely fine.

However, remember that the RAM will work at the speed of the slowest component.  If you stick 1333 and 1066 RAM in the same machine, all the RAM will work - but at the 1066 speed.

As pointed out by DanielB - the speed decrease is almost negligable, but there will be one - and additional RAM is almost always better than the speed reduction.

Comment: More memory is almost always better, considering the virtually negligible bandwidth difference.

Comment: true, answer updated